# How do I delete lines using PHP that do NOT contain a designated string?

Tags: php, php-curl

I have the following text block containing names in their own line:

```
Sarah Jane Smith
Archie Jones
Micky Smith
Rose Tyler
Harriet Jones
Jack Harkness
John Smith
Martha Jones
Donna Noble
```

Using PHP, I want to delete all the lines that do NOT contain Jones and leave the lines containing Jones, as follows:

```
Archie Jones
Harriet Jones
Martha Jones
```

There are several answers that show how to delete lines that contain a word, but no answers that provide a method of deleting all those that don't contain the key string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would do this is to split the text block into an array with an entry for each line:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

Then filter out the lines that don't include the name you want:

```
$remaining = array_filter($lines, function($line) {
     return strpos($line, 'Jones') !== false;
});
```

Then you can rejoin the array with the values you want

```
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $remaining);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for arrays that can fit into memory. If you have huge file you need another approach.

Comment: @Boy Yes that's a good point. This should work for medium to small data sets. For anything larger OP would need to either look into reading the names in as a stream or save it to a file and go line by line using something like `fgets` or `stream_get_line`

Comment: I have a personal hosting account, and my file is rarely over 60,000 lines. This is precisely what I need, so this is an excellent answer. I consider the answer SOLVED. Excellent answer, jfadich.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match all the lines that *do* contain Jones, then combine the matches.

```
preg_match_all('/.*Jones.*/m', $text, $matches);
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```